# Prove similarity in a triangle

Tags: geometry

This is a question from a school textbook (Extended Math for IGCSE by David Reyner), so I'm guessing it shouldn't be too hard to solve for you guys. Anyway, here it is:

In a triangle ABC, a line is drawn parallel to BC to meet AB at D and AC at E. DC and BE meet at X. Prove that:
(a) the triangles ADE and ABC are similar. (Done)
(b) the triangle DXE and BXC are similar. (Done)
(c) AD / AB = EX / XB

Comment: If a) and b) are done, then you don't need to see the solutions for these, right? Your only question is c) ?

Comment: Yes, both questions are just given because they usually provide hints.

Comment: It is true that DXE and BXC are similar, but sloppily expressed, since D is not what corresponds to B. It really should be "DXE similar to CXB".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint 2: You have two pairs of simliar triangles. Is there any corresponding pair of edges that are in both pairs of triangles?

Comment: Helped a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: From b), find another ratio equal to EX / XB.

Comment: I give up. I tried, but really, I suck at these proof sums. Any chance you could explain?

Comment: Amaan, do you understand that if two triangles are similar, then the ratios of corresponding sides are all equal? So (b) gives you two ratios that are equal to EX/XB, and one of those two ratios relates to (a) as well....

Answer (score 1):

ok from a) you get $\frac{AD}{AB}=\frac{AE}{EC}=\frac{DE}{BC}....~(1)$ as the triangles are similar the ratio of their sides will be in same proportion.  Now, similarly for b) you get  $\frac{EX}{BX}=\frac{DX}{CX}=\frac{DE}{BC}....~(2)$ both $(1)\text{ and }(2)$ has $\frac{DE}{CB}~$ common $~\therefore \frac{AD}{AB}=\frac{EX}{XB}\quad$ as they both are equal to $\frac{DE}{BC}~$ from $(1) \text{ and }(2)$.

Hope this helps.